# GPUImage2 analyse brightness

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

I want to analyse an image in realtime to see if it is brighter then the one before.
Is GPUImage a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

An AverageLuminanceExtractor operation will get you the average luminance of an incoming frame. However, by default the iOS camera will try to automatically balance this, so you'll typically see results around 0.5 all the time.

You'll need to control the exposure of the camera to obtain a more absolute measure of external luminance with this operation.